# Convergent sequence in complete metric space that is not Cauchy?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know that Cauchy sequences in metric spaces can fail to converge (but if the metric space is complete, they always converge). Can there be a convergent sequence (perhaps in a complete metric space) that is not Cauchy, or does "Cauchyness" follow from convergence in a complete space?

Comment: I think that convergence implies Cauchy in *any* metric space, not just complete metic spaces.

Comment: Convergent sequences are always Cauchy.

Comment: ["Every convergent sequence is a Cauchy sequence ..."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence#Other_properties)

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n =x.$ Then $$d(x_n,x_m)\leq d(x_n,x)+d(x,x_m)\to0 \text{ as }n,m\to\infty$$
Hence, every convergent sequence in any metric space is Cauchy.